# Add sequential counter to group within dataframe but skip increment when condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking to setup an incremental counter with a group in a dataframe. I would like to increase the counter for each row within the group unless a condition is met. If the condition is met I want to use the previous count. I also want this to reset for every group.

example:

```
d1 = {'col1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'col2': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df1
```

output:

```
   col1 col2
0   1   A
1   1   A
2   1   B
3   2   A
4   2   A
5   3   B
```

expected output:

```
  col1 col2 count
0   1   A   1
1   1   A   2
2   1   B   2
3   2   A   1
4   2   A   2
5   3   B   0
```

I have tried using numpy cumsum. But I am not really sure how to reuse the last cumsum

Edit:
Looking to Group by Column 1.

Comment: Is your group determined by col1 or col2 ? could you specify the conditions that the count would be set to previous value ? it's not totally clear

Comment: Sorry about that the group should be determined by col1

Comment: In this case, row 5 should be count 1 not 0 ? So col1 it's the group, col2 is the condition ?

Comment: yes Col2 is the condition. Row 5 is 0 because I do not want to increment the counter when col2 is B. But since that is the first row in the group, it should be 0.

Comment: thinking this way first row should be count 0 as well.

 I have a suggestion for a general approach, so just to confirm your condition is simply looking if the next row has a col2 value different than the previous row, correct ?

Comment: Col2 only has two values A or B. If a row has the value A I want to increment the counter by 1. If the row has a value B do not increment the counter.
I also created a new column where if col2 is A the value is 1 and if the col2 is B the value is 0 and then run a cumsum. But that seems to be breaking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a code snippet following what I believe is what you want, you can definitely reuse to adapt if something is not really exactly as you expected.

I think the key thing here is:
1) iterate on the pairs of (previousRow, currentRow) so you can easily acess last row information

2) specific if conditions that matches what you expect.

3) try to update the count in the if conditions and set the value afterwards

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
from itertools import zip_longest
d1 = {'col1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'col2': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

df1['count'] = 0
df1_previterrows = df1.iterrows()
df1_curriterrows = df1.iterrows()
df1_curriterrows.__next__()

groups_counter = {}

df1_firstRow = df1.iloc[0]
if df1_firstRow["col2"] == "A":
    groups_counter[df1_firstRow['col1']]=1
    df1.set_value(0, 'count', 1)
elif df1_firstRow["col2"] == "B":
    groups_counter["B"]=1
    df1.set_value(0, 'count', 0)

zip_list = zip_longest(df1_previterrows, df1_curriterrows) 
for (prevRow_idx, prevRow), Curr  in zip_list:
    if not (Curr is None):
        (currRow_idx, currRow) = Curr
        if((currRow["col1"] == prevRow["col1"]) and (currRow["col2"] == "A")):
            count = groups_counter.get(currRow["col1"],False)
            if not count:
                groups_counter[currRow["col1"]]=0
            groups_counter[currRow["col1"]]+=1

        elif((currRow["col1"] != prevRow["col1"]) and (currRow["col2"] == "A")):
            groups_counter[currRow["col1"]]=1

        elif((currRow["col1"] == prevRow["col1"]) and (currRow["col2"] == "B")):
            if not groups_counter.get(currRow["col1"],False):
                groups_counter[curr["col1"]] = 1

        elif((currRow["col1"] != prevRow["col1"]) and (currRow["col2"] == "B")):
            groups_counter[currRow["col1"]]=0
        df1.set_value(currRow_idx, 'count', groups_counter[currRow["col1"]])
print(df1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   col1 col2  count
0     1    A      1
1     1    A      2
2     1    B      2
3     2    A      1
4     2    A      2
5     3    B      0
```